# Selenium setTimeout command being ignored in WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using WebDriverBackedSelenium

I notice that the selenium.setTimeout() command is being ignored completely.
Anyone else face this issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: In what way is it being ignored? Some commands in both WebDriver & WebDriverBackedSelenium will be blocking calls, and as such the old way of `setTimeout()` won't be applicable to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO two possibilities for resolving:

```
WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();   
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

2nd way:

```
Thread.sleep(...miliseconds...)
```

depending upon purposes you gonna to use it.